# boundness of linear map

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis

Let $X$ and $Y$ be Banach spaces, $T : X\rightarrow Y$ a linear map such that $f \circ T\in X^*$ for every $f\in Y^*$, then $T$ is bounded.

I've tried to show that $T$ is closed, but I think that's something wrong with my proof: Suppose 
$$\lim_{n\to \infty}(x_n,Tx_n)=(x,y),$$
given $f\in Y^*$, $f \circ T$ is continuous so
$$\lim_{n\to \infty}f \circ T(x_n)=f \circ T(x).$$
Now, $\lim_{n\to \infty} T(x_n)=y$ and $f$ is continuous, so 
$\lim_{n\to \infty}f(T(x_n))=f(y)$. Hence, $\forall f\in Y^*$, $f(y-Tx)=0$, then by Hann-Banach $y=Tx$.

Comment: Your proof looks good to me.